# Assigning value to hidden input type

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Is their something wrong if i write this code in jsp ?

```
<%String namee=rs.getString(2);%>
<input name="IndUserName"  type="hidden" value=namee/>
```

Am i wrong in assigning value to this input?

Comment: I think: value="${namee}" or old way: value="<%=namee%>"

Comment: you should put in in between single or double quotes, and escape single/double quotes from it, but besides that you CAN do it. What's your concern exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  <%String namee=rs.getString(2);%>
  <input name="IndUserName"  type="hidden" value="<%=namee %>"/>
```

your variable namee is used as <%=namee %> in jsp

Comment: What is difference from my 11 minutes old comment?

Comment: Why even bother making a variable if this is all you use it for? `<input name="IndUserName"  type="hidden" value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%String namee=rs.getString(2);%>
<input name="IndUserName"  type="hidden" value="<%=namee%>"/>
```

This is for script style jsp.

If you are looking for JSF (which I would recommend), it would be #{Bean.namee}, where Bean is the name of your backing bean, namee is a property of that bean.

Comment: What is difference from my 11 minutes old comment?